# In what cases is Polymorphism useful?

Tags: object-oriented, polymorphism

I know how Polymorphism works, but I am trying to understand in what cases is Polymorphism useful.

Now All the examples that I have found about Polymorphism are one of the following (the below code is in C++):

- Either we have an array of type `Base*` that holds pointers to objects derived from the `Base` class, and then we loop through the array and call something like `Base->foo()`
- Or we have a function that have a `Base*` parameter, and then we call this function and pass it a pointer to any of the objects derived from the `Base` class

Are these the only cases where Polymorphism is useful?

Comment: You're talking about the mechanics of polymorphism, not its practical uses.

Comment: One of my favorites is this polymorphic button on my mouse. It does all sorts of different things.

Comment: see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: maybe you want to take a look with [Why to use Polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11064425/3165499)

Comment: Note that C++ has other polymorphism, e.g. `std::sort` is polymorphic in both *what* and *how* you are sorting